# Upgrading to Highstock 1.3

Tags: highcharts

I have upgraded to latest Highstock 1.3.

I have enabled `dataLabels` with `borderRadius` for my series.

In IE, Chart gets rendered with extra height for data labels.

This can be seen on Highchart fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-datalabels-box/).

Snapshot:

[image]

Also, the default positioning for data labels has changed in latest `Highstock 1.3`. Now it renders values bit higher than earlier version.

I am using

`dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            y: -3
                        }`

for `spline` series. Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mhardik/2AsaP/).

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: It appears in all IE ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it looks like a bug, so I've reported it here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1669